# Android - swap views in LinearLayout via xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Here is my xml code, it has an ImageView which stands before LinearLayout id = "linearLayout2" :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_swap"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/fromStationField"
                android:completionThreshold="1"
                android:hint="From"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:gravity="left|start"
                android:layout_gravity="left" />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/toStationField"
                android:completionThreshold="1"
                android:hint="To"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:paddingRight="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What I want to do is to make an ImageView stands after the LinearLayout id = "linearLayout2" like I show in an image bellow.

How to do this using only xml ?

[image]

Comment: So you need the imageview at the right side rather than left??

Comment: sJy, Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the layout below, I'm using negative margins in the `ImageView` and a positive margin in the `LinearLayout` container left of `ImageView` so that we don't need to use `layout_weight` property and can keep using `match_parent`. For this you need to fix the size of your `ImageView`. Check this code out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp">



        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/fromStationField"
                android:completionThreshold="1"
                android:hint="From"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:gravity="left|start"
                android:layout_gravity="left" />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/toStationField"
                android:completionThreshold="1"
                android:hint="To"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:paddingRight="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_swap"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-55dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It work, so do you use approximately width of image in  android:layout_marginLeft="-55dp" ?

Comment: @gigs Actually, I fixed the `ImageView` height and width to 50dp each. Then, I added 5dp margin (for aesthetics reasons) and set that as negative margin. If I were to change the width of `ImageView` to 60dp, I'll use -65dp for margin and so on.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be inside of linearLayout1 to move the ImageView after linearLayout2. Then set linearLayout1's width to match_parent and the sibling views width to 0dp. Lastly, use layout_weight to achieve the proportion of size you want for the ImageView and LinearLayout2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="9"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/fromStationField"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:completionThreshold="1"
                android:gravity="left|start"
                android:hint="From"
                android:textAlignment="textStart" />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/toStationField"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:completionThreshold="1"
                android:hint="To"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:paddingRight="4dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_swap" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```